# How to hide Visio 2007's UML parameter direction indicator ("in/out")

Tags: uml, visio

I Googled and searched here for the solution, the only thing I've found it to override the text and edit it manually - however this will be changed as soon as you make a change to the object.

I'd like to hide the "in" direction indicator for method parameters - anyone know if it's possible to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing some research, here's what I found:

- There is no GUI option to toggle the visibility of the `direction` indicator
- A workaround would be to create a new `master` (copying the original `class` master), and tweak it to change the display of `Operations` shape.
- However, there is no option in the `Shapesheet` window to do that.
- The next thing to try would be manipulate it via code.
- After fiddling around, I couldn't find any public properties that allowed you to set that.
- I stumbled upon this [technet forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/72ad591e-0914-40fb-b718-0ddc2125f250/) which confirmed my suspicion (that the UML addon lacked a good set of APIs).

So I guess the short answer is - No. There is no automatic way of doing that in Visio 2007/2010.

There are other tools that let you control this, such as:

- Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect [(Class Diagrams)](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_classdiagram.html)
- IBM's Rational Software Architect [(Showing or hiding parameters)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cparam.html)

If you can switch tools, I would recommend Enterprise Architect. It has allows C# code generation (not sure about IBM) and has Visual Studio integration as well.

Hope ths helps!

Comment: At least I can finally have closure... ;)
I will look into the tools you mentioned, thanks!